# How do I call methods with reference variables with Expression Trees

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I am trying to figure out how to create an Expression that calls a method which has a reference parameter.

Let me explain my question with a simple (but artificial) example.  Consider the method:

```
    public static int TwiceTheInput(int x)
    {
        return x*2;
    }
```

I can create an Expression to call the above method by doing something like:

```
    {
        var inputVar = Expression.Variable(typeof (int), "input");
        var blockExp =
            Expression.Block(
                    new[] {inputVar}
                    , Expression.Assign(inputVar, Expression.Constant(10))
                    , Expression.Assign(inputVar, Expression.Call(GetType().GetMethod("TwiceTheInput", new[] { typeof(int) }), inputVar))
                    , inputVar
                    );
        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(blockExp).Compile()();
    }
```

On execution, the "result" above should end up with a value of 20.
Now consider a version of TwiceTheInput() that uses by-reference parameters:

```
    public static void TwiceTheInputByRef(ref int x)
    {
        x = x * 2;
    }
```

How do I write a similar Expression Tree to call TwiceTheInputByRef() and pass arguments by reference to it?

Solution:   (Thanks to Cicada).  Use:

```
Type.MakeByRefType()
```

Here's a code segment to generate the Expression Tree:

```
        {
        var inputVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "input");
        var blockExp =
            Expression.Block(
                    new[] { inputVar }
                    , Expression.Assign(inputVar, Expression.Constant(10))
                    , Expression.Call(GetType().GetMethod("TwiceTheInputByRef", new[] { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() }), inputVar)
                    , inputVar
                    );
        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(blockExp).Compile()();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a lambda expression to call the same method, getting the C# compiler to convert that to an expression tree, and then decompiling? That's normally what I do to work out how to build expression trees :)

Comment: No, I haven't done it before.  Any url that walks through an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to change much, just remove the `Assign` and change `typeof(int)` to `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()`.

```
var blockExp = Expression.Block(
    new[] { inputVar }
    , Expression.Assign(inputVar, Expression.Constant(10))
    , Expression.Call(
       typeof(Program).GetMethod( 
           "TwiceTheInputByRef", new [] { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() }),
       inputVar)
    , inputVar
);
```

Comment: Don't recall off the top of my head, but could one use the (semi undocumented) __makeref keyword here? You'd need an actual variable, naturally.

Comment: @JerKimball As you said indeed, `__makeref` works on variables, not types, so we can't use it here. Note that the `MakeByRefType` part is just used by `GetMethod` to resolve the appropriate overload of `TwiceTheInputByRef`: if there's no overload, that second argument is superfluous.

Comment: Does Type.MakeByRefType() work equally well for both ref and out parameters?   (It seems to work in a quick test that I tried..)

Comment: Yes, an `out` parameter is "by ref".