# Use DLR to invoke a method with ref parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic

Trying to invoke a sample method taking a ref parameter:

```
public void RefTest(ref int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i = 18;
}
```

Utilizing the DLR:

```
var prog = new Program();
var binder = Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember(
    CSharpBinderFlags.ResultDiscarded,
    "RefTest", null, typeof(Program),
    new CSharpArgumentInfo[]{
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(0,null),
        CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsRef,null)
    }
);
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
Expression dyn = Expression.Dynamic(binder, typeof(object), Expression.Constant(prog), p);
var lam = Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(dyn, p).Compile();
lam(9); //RuntimeBinderException
```

However, the code fails with RuntimeBinderException that it can't convert int to ref int. How to fix it?

I am trying to mimic the following code:

```
dynamic prog = new Program();
Action<int> lam = i => prog.RefTest(ref i);
lam(9);
```

I have to use DLR instead of reflection, because the supplied object (`prog`) may be dynamic.

Comment: While http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146317/create-expression-to-invoke-method-with-out-parameter is about `out` rather than `ref`, the same problem applies and the same answer solves, unless I'm missing a further difference.

Comment: @Jon Wrong. This uses the DLR, not reflection. Also setting the parameter type to `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()` does not help, if that's what you expected the answer.

Comment: @IllidanS4 the other example uses Expression trees in the same way you do. Are you mixing up DLR with runtime creation of expressions?

Comment: @Bas Duh, I am - don't you see `Expression.Dynamic`?

Comment: @IllidanS4 just making sure this is intended

Comment: There are projects like [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) that make it a lot easier to work with the DLR. I'm admittedly not sure upfront that it will help you, but it helped me a while ago.

Comment: Ought to be covered by [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940171/how-do-i-call-methods-with-reference-variables-with-expression-trees).

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your problem and found a few potential issues with the code in question. To explain, I'll start with how I interpreted what you are actually trying to do, which is run the following code:

```
dynamic program = ...;
program.RefTest(ref myInt);
```

Note that the above code works fine and runs the method.

A few things to note here:

- The `program` variable is a constant.
- The method returns `void`
- We should be able to pass in any integer by reference.

Some things in your question that do not align with this are:

- Your `Expression.Dynamic` call tells the method to return `object`. Instead it should return `typeof(void)`.
- Your `Expression.Lambda` call specifies the delegate type as an `Action<int>`. The parameter should be of type `ref int`. To solve this there should be an `Action` that has `ref` parameters instead. `delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T arg1)`

This has brought me to the following code:

```
Expression programExpr = Expression.Constant(program);
var binder = Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.ResultDiscarded | CSharpBinderFlags.InvokeSimpleName, "Bla", null, typeof (Program),
    new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), 
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsRef, null) });
var intParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof (int).MakeByRefType(), "x");
Expression methodCall = Expression.Dynamic(binder, typeof (void), programExpr, intParam);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<RefAction<int>>(methodCall, intParam).Compile();
expr(ref myInt);
```

However, I get the same exception as you:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot convert type 'int' to 'ref int'

This leads me to believe there is some framework bug that causes the `RuntimeBinder` to incorrectly handle `ref` parameters for dynamic invocation, or that the `Expression.Dynamic` code incorrectly assigns by value parameters where `ref` parameters should be used.

Note that I was able to reproduce the issue for `out` parameters as well, yielding the exact same result.

For you situation however, you already appear to know so much about the types you are going to invoke, and even create a strongly typed delegate to invoke. In that case I would go with the following:

```
var programExpr = Expression.Constant(program);
var intParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int).MakeByRefType(), "x");
var methodCall = Expression.Call(programExpr, typeof (Program)
    .GetMethod("RefTest", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance), intParam);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<RefAction<int>>(methodCall, intParam).Compile();
expr(ref myInt);
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but I need to use the DLR in case the object was dynamic (ref and out parameters are supported on dynamic objects).

Comment: @IllidanS4 That's why I mentioned the likelyhood that you can't do it because of a runtime bug. I hope you solve it but it feels like something that cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, [Dynamic doesn't support ref/out parameters](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6403220a-1b8f-4e4a-9b97-39ba68f6fff7/can-i-use-ref-and-out-arguments-with-a-dynamic-method-when-implementing-a-dynamicobject?forum=csharplanguage). Refer 
Alexandra Rusina's answer in the linked thread and [here also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502924/2530848).

Try the following (which won't compile):

```
dynamic value = 5;
RefTest(ref value);
```

Simply dynamic don't support ref/out. So obviously trying the same with expressions also won't work.

Comment: How I read the question is that the parameter is strongly typed. It's just dynamic invocation that the OP is asking for...

Comment: @Bas You may be right. Not sure I'm missing the actual question. I believe this is a XY question though. After reading your answer I believe, ref and dynmaic doesn't work together well.